# Winforms Control Autosize Doesn't Account for Scroll Bars

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a simple winform app which has a limited number of controls.  Here is the Document Outline:
[image]

Everything I can find on the TableLayoutPanel and FlowLayoutPanels are set to Autosize=true.

When the app is big enough to fit all of the controls, the scroll bars are not present.
[image]

When the window is resized horizontally such that all the controls are no longer shown, the scroll bars automatically appear.  What I can't seem to figure out is how to make the control autosize vertically to account for the presence of the horizontal scroll bar, since there is plenty of vertical space.

[image]

Edit: it was postulated that the flowlayout panels could be an issue.  I refactored things to test that.  It is now a 2 row tablelayoutpanel with 4 columns.  Unfortunately, it didn't change the behaviour.

Before sizing:

[image]

After sizing:

[image]

Comment: Why do you have those `FlowLayoutPanels` at all? Why don't you just four rows and four columns in your `TableLayoutPanel`. Maybe I'm missing something but the inner containers don't appear to be necessary.

Comment: In reality, I have a mix of controls inside those flow layout panels.  I just dropped a bunch of checkboxes into this example to simplify and demonstrate the issue.  The flowlayout panel allows me to group a couple rows of small things to be similar in size to a big thing.  Do you think the flowlayoutpanel is part of the problem?  I could redo this w/o them to check.

Comment: I'd have to do some testing to know for sure, which I don't time to do right now, but I am wondering whether the `FlowLayoutPanels` might be part of the problem.

Comment: Not the ```FlowLayoutPanels```.  See edit above.

Comment: I'm having trouble reproducing your issue. Note that there are several options for resizing: `AutoSize`, `Dock`, `Anchor`, `WrapContents` so it might be a case of working out which combination is best. Also, I think controls resize in a particular order.

Comment: Also, have you tried the `MinimumSize` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what ultimately worked.  Basically, when the form is shown, recursively get all controls in the `TableLayoutPanel` checking the min/max coordinates.  When the form is resized, check if the Horizontal Scroll Bar is shown and set the `MinimumSize` accordingly.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private mincoord As Integer
    Private maxcoord As Integer

    Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
        mincoord = getMinCoordinate(TableLayoutPanel1)
        maxcoord = getMaxCoordinate(TableLayoutPanel1)
        Form1_ResizeEnd(Me, New EventArgs)
    End Sub

    Private Function getMinCoordinate(ctrl As Control) As Integer
        Dim toRtn As Integer = ctrl.Top - ctrl.Margin.Top - ctrl.Padding.Top
        'Debug.Print(ctrl.Name & "min: " & toRtn)

        For Each currCtrl As Control In ctrl.Controls
            toRtn = Math.Min(toRtn, getMinCoordinate(currCtrl))
        Next

        Return toRtn
    End Function

    Private Function getMaxCoordinate(ctrl As Control) As Integer
        Dim toRtn As Integer = ctrl.Bottom + ctrl.Margin.Bottom + ctrl.Padding.Bottom
        'Debug.Print(ctrl.Name & "max: " & toRtn)

        For Each currCtrl As Control In ctrl.Controls
            toRtn = Math.Max(toRtn, getMaxCoordinate(currCtrl))
        Next

        Return toRtn
    End Function

    Private Sub Form1_ResizeEnd(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.ResizeEnd
        TableLayoutPanel1.MinimumSize = New Size(TableLayoutPanel1.MinimumSize.Width, maxcoord - mincoord + If(TableLayoutPanel1.HorizontalScroll.Visible, SystemInformation.HorizontalScrollBarHeight, 0))
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

Set `MinimumSize` Height property on your container. This is to ensure that your container takes up a greater proportion of the form when the form is reduced below its original height.

Comment: That does seem to work, though it feels a little kludgy.  I'd also need to manually figure out the contents of a TableLayoutPanel to know the formula.  Is this what you had in mind?


```Private Sub Form1_ResizeEnd(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.ResizeEnd
    TableLayoutPanel1.MinimumSize = New Size(TableLayoutPanel1.MinimumSize.Width, 2 * (CheckBox1.Height + CheckBox1.Margin.Top + CheckBox1.Margin.Bottom) + If(TableLayoutPanel1.HorizontalScroll.Visible, SystemInformation.HorizontalScrollBarHeight, 0))
End Sub```